# Spring hashing password in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, jasypt

I have a spring java project (not boot)
I am trying to hash the password in the applicationContext.xml (Spring Configuration File)

So I followed the instructions on the web to use jasypt
Steps I followed : I changed the password to

```
<property name="password" value="ENC("DSDFGSDF/DSDFGSDF#234538SDFg/SM1P4A6Q)" />
```

and I added Jasypt 192 jar to the class path
but i'm getting this error from oracle so I guess its not working

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Did i miss a step on using jasypt

Comment: Did you configure the jasypt bean as well? http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html#Integrating_jasypt_with_Springs_application_configuration_infrastructure

Comment: I have only one bean  environmentVariablesConfiguration defined is this sufficient?

Comment: You need to add in jasypt's configurator for Spring to handle the decryption. Just having the JAR will not be sufficient. Should be wherever you configure Spring, like a spring.factories file, for example.